# How do I dynamically generate JPA Id column based on parent?

Tags: java, jpa, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a JSON file that looks like this...

```
{
  "accountId": "123",
  "parties":[
    {
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can parse this fine using something like

```
public class Account{
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty("parties")
  private List<Party> parties;
}

public class Party{
  private String name;
}
```

However, the SQL table PARTY contains a compound key as the ID. This is a compound key of the name and the parent's account id. Is there a way I can do this without separate classes? I tried this...

```
@JsonBackReference
private Account parent;

public class GetIdConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String b) {
        if(parent == null){
            logger.error("couldn't find the parent");
        }
        return parent.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

But when I try to insert I get...

> IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are only two options for defining composite keys in JPA: `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId` annotations, and in both cases we have to create a separate class. The basic idea behind creating a class for a composite class is to understand that our key contains multiple primary key fields and treat this object as atomic. The idea of a composite key as a class makes it easy to work with an entity key in any structure that implements JPA.

Like option you can unite two classes into single entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(PartyEntity.PartyId.class)
public class PartyEntity {

    public static class PartyId implements Serializable {
        private String accountId;

        private String name;

        public PartyId() {
        }

        public PartyId(String accountId, String name) {
            this.accountId = accountId;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof PartyId)) return false;
            PartyId partyId = (PartyId) o;
            return Objects.equals(accountId, partyId.accountId) &&
                    Objects.equals(name, partyId.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(accountId, name);
        }
    }

    @Id
    private String accountId;

    @Id
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement to saver's answer - you could try the following mapping:

```
public class Account{
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("parties")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Party> parties;
}

@IdClass(PartyEntity.PartyId.class)
public class Party {

    @JsonBackReference
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;


    @Id
    private String name;
}
```

See the first example in the 'Examples of Derived Identifiers' section of the [spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)

Comment: Sorry still haven't had time to try this but hopefully today thank you!